# Validar input dentro de tabla en javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

Tengo una tabla donde genero las filas de manera dinámica por medio de `JavaScript`, dentro de cada fila hay 2 `input` y 2 `select` que debo validar si están vacíos o no antes de dar click en botón de guardar.

Cómo podria validar que los campos no estén vacíos y solo permita cuando estan con datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi `HMTL`, donde a la tabla con **id="list-activities"** le voy agregando las filas dinámicamente con `JavaScript`, cuando doy click a un botón me genera todas las filas.

```
<div id="PageLoadProgresAct" class="p-2 mb-2" style="display:none;margin:0 auto;width:120px;border:#014c8d 1px solid;background-color:#eeeeee"><img src="{{asset('images/gif/Progress-circle.gif')}}" alt="Progress"><span class="ml-1" style="color: #0069A5;font-size:12.5px">Cargando...</span></div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-12 table-responsive">                        
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover text-center">
                                <thead style="color:#ffffff; background-color: rgb(33,136,201)">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Item</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Actividad</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Etapa Fabricación</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Prioridad</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Fec.Inicio</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Fin.Previsto</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col">Estado</th>
                                        <th class="align-text-top text-sm" scope="col"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody class="text-sm" id="list-activities">
                                    <tr id="nodataActivity">
                                        <td colspan="12">No hay datos ingresados...</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Este es mi código `Javascript` donde genera las filas cuando doy click en un botón aparte del formulario.

Al generar las filas las columnas **Etapa, prioridad, fecha de inicio y fecha prevista** están vacíos donde el usuarios ingresara datos y quisiera poder validar que cuando de click no permita si están vacíos.

```
function add_total_activity() {

    let tableBodyAT = document.getElementById('listActivities');
    let tableBodyA = document.getElementById('list-activities');

    for (let i = 0, row; row = tableBodyAT.rows[i]; i++) {
        for (let j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
            c_activity++;
            $('#nodataActivity').remove();
            let newRow = tableBodyA.insertRow(-1);
            let count = tableBodyA.rows.length;
            newRow.innerHTML = '<th scope="row" style="font-size:12px">' + count + '</th><input type="hidden" value="' + c_activity + '"><td style="font-size:12px" class="fw-bold name name_activity_n">' + col.innerText + '</td><td><select style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center fw-bold stage_id_n" name="stage_id"><option value="">Seleccionar...</option><option value="1">Acondicionamiento de materiales</option><option value="2">Trabajo de Ensamblaje</option><option value="3">Trabajo de Soldadura</option><option value="4">Prueba Hidrostatica/Hermeticidad</option><option value="5">Trabajo de Acabados/Limpieza</option></td><td><select style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm text-center fw-bold priority_n" name="priority"><option value="">Seleccionar...</option><option value="Crítica">Crítica</option><option value="Alta">Alta</option><option value="Media">Media</option><option value="Baja">Baja</option></select></td><td><input type="date" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext fw-bold text-center bg-light start_date_n" name="start_date" value=""></td><td><input type="date" style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm form-control-plaintext fw-bold text-center bg-light expected_date_n" name="expected_date" value=""></td><td><select style="font-size:12px" class="form-control form-control-sm bg-white fw-bold text-center status_activity_n" disabled name="status_activity"><option value="1" selected>Asignado</option></select></td><td><button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="delete_row_project_activity(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>';
        }
    }
}
```

Esta es la función donde hago el guardado de los datos enviando por `AJAX` a mi controller.

```
function store_activities() {
    c_activity = 0;
    document.querySelectorAll('#list-activities tr').forEach(function (e) {
        c_activity++;
        let object = {
            c_activity: c_activity,
            name: e.querySelector('.name_activity_n').innerHTML,
            priority: e.querySelector('.priority_n').value,
            start_date: e.querySelector('.start_date_n').value,
            expected_date: e.querySelector('.expected_date_n').value,
            stage_id: e.querySelector('.stage_id_n').value,
            status: e.querySelector('.status_activity_n').value,
            project_id: document.getElementById('project_id').value
        };
        
        actividades.push(object);
       
    });
    console.log(actividades); 
   
    let objetos = JSON.stringify(actividades);

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/activity/store',
        data: { objetos: objetos },
        statusCode: {
            200: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                $('#project-activities-modal').modal('hide');
                limpiar();
                Swal.fire(
                    'Bien hecho!',
                    response['message'],
                    'success'
                ).then(function () {
                    actividades = [];
                    tableProject.ajax.reload();
                });
            },
            500: function () {
                console.log('Error');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: se deben validar todos los elementos de tabla? podrias colocar el codigo html de tu tabla ya renderizada en el doom para ver los inputs y los names que tienen estos?

Comment: Claro ahora edito y lo armó ya con la estructura que se tiene al final y si debería validar cada input de cada fila no esté vacío

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una clase compartida a todos los elementos que quieres validar y ejecutar una función al hacer click en el botón. El script se detendrá y enfocará el primer elemento que encuentre vacío.

*Reemplaza el alert por las funciones que envían la petición para guardar cuando se cumpla que no hayan campos vacíos.*

```js
$('#validarVacios').on('click', function() {
  //Contar los campos que comparten clase
  let cantidad = $('.validar').length;
  //Inicializar un contador
  let contador = 0;
  //Marcar con borde rojo todos los vacíos
  $('.validar').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $(this).addClass('border-danger');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('border-danger');
    }
  });
  //Hacer foco en el primer vacío
  $('.validar').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      $(this).focus();
      return false;
    }
    contador++;
  });
  //Validar que no hayan vacíos
  if(cantidad === contador){
    //Guardar cuando se cumpla
    alert('No hay vacíos!');
  }
});
```

```css
.border-danger{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="validar">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="validar">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="date" class="validar"></td>
    <td><input type="date" class="validar"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="validar">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="validar">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="date" class="validar"></td>
    <td><input type="date" class="validar"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="validarVacios">AGREGAR</button>
```

Ten en cuenta que los script siempre van al final del documento, antes del cierre de la etiqueta `</body>`.

Comment: DjCrazy, gracias estuve probando el codigo y se coloca el foco en el campo donde este vacio. Adicional a eso agregue un clase para que se ponga el campo de color rojo; pero como podria hacer para que todos los campos se coloquen del color rojo y no solo quede en el primer input vacio.

Comment: let cantidad = $('.validarRow').length;    
    let contador = 0;
    $('.validarRow').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $(this).focus();
            $(this).addClass('border'); 
            $(this).addClass('border-danger');          
            return false;
        }
        else{
            $(this).removeClass('border'); 
            $(this).removeClass('border-danger');       
        }
        contador++;
    });
  
    if (cantidad === contador) {     
        alert('No hay vacíos!');
    }

Comment: Se me ocurre rápidamente agregar un nuevo ciclo para maracar en rojo todos los campos vacíos y posteriormente el otro ciclo para enfocar el primer vacío. Edite la respuesta con el nuevo ciclo y con el `CSS`.

Comment: Muchas, gracias me ayudo mucho, anteriormente solo habia realizado con queryselectall recorria la tabla y sus filas, pero cuando aplicaba querySelector('validar') con la clase, solo me marcaba la primera fila y no las demás.

Answer (score 0):

Una fila se considera no vacía cuando tiene definidos los valores para etapa, prioridad, fecha inicio y fecha término. Podemos definir una función `isRowComplete` que recibe un elemento `tr` y devuelve verdadero o falso.

```
function isRowComplete(row) {
  const {
    priority: e.querySelector('.priority_n').value,
    start_date: e.querySelector('.start_date_n').value,
    expected_date: e.querySelector('.expected_date_n').value,
    stage_id: e.querySelector('.stage_id_n').value
  };
  return priority && start_date && expected_date && stage_id
}
```

Luego antes de tu llamada ajax puedes contar cuántas filas están incompletas, y retornar cuando no sean cero:

```
function store_activities() {

   const filas_incompletas = Array.from(
       document.querySelectorAll('#list-activities tr')
    ).filter(tr => !isRowComplete(tr)).length;

    if(filas_incompletas!==0) return;
    c_activity = 0;
    ....
 }
```

te queda de tarea mostrar algún mensaje informativo en vez de sólo retornar